# Layer in WP LayerSlider does not fire hover event

Tags: jquery, wordpress, events, hover

A have a LayerSlider with multiple layers. I want to perform an action when the user hovers over one particular layer. But it seems like the hover event is not fired. Does LayerSlider somehow prevent firing the event? Or is there some plugin setting that has to be changed?

My layer code is basically this:

```
<div class="layer1"></div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$("div.layer1").hover(function() {
    console.log("hover event fired");
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do something like that :

```
if("div.layer1").is(":visible") {
    $(".LayerSlider ").hover(function() {
        console.log("hover event fired");
    }
}
```